# TypeError: Argument must be rect style object - Pygame (Python

Tags: python, list, pygame, rect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pygame (Python) - TypeError: Argument must be rect style object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305083/pygame-python-typeerror-argument-must-be-rect-style-object)

I am trying to make a brick breaker game in Pygame (with Python) but I am stuck at an error.

(this is random text that is necessary so I can post all this code)

CODE:

```
import pygame, sys, time, random
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
fpsclock = pygame.time.Clock()

WINDOWWIDTH = 450
WINDOWHEIGHT = 650
mainwindow = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Luzion - Brick Breaker')

paddle = pygame.image.load('Brick Breaker - Paddle.png')
paddlerect = paddle.get_rect()
paddlerect.topleft = (190, 575)

ball = pygame.image.load ('ball.png')
ballrect = ball.get_rect()
ballrect.topleft = (195, 565)

cooltext = pygame.image.load('cooltext1.png')
cooltextrect = cooltext.get_rect()
cooltextrect.topleft = (0, 0)

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 128, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
LIME = (0, 255, 0)
TEXTCOLOR = WHITE

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)

def displaytext(text, font, surface, x, y):
    text = font.render(text, 1, TEXTCOLOR)
    textrect = text.get_rect()
    textrect.topleft = (x, y)
    surface.blit(text, textrect)

def waitforplayer():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                return

rb = pygame.image.load('redblock.png')
rb2 = rb1 = rb
level1blocks = [rb, rb1, rb2]
rbrect = rb.get_rect().topleft = (0, 0)
rb1rect = rb1.get_rect().topleft = (40, 0)
rb2rect = rb2.get_rect().topleft = (80, 0)
level1rects = [rbrect, rb1rect, rb2rect]

moveleft = False
moveright = False
SPEED = 7

bmoveup = bmovedown = bmoveleft = bmoveright = False
BALLSPEED = 8

mainwindow.blit(cooltext, cooltextrect)
pygame.display.update()
time.sleep(1)

displaytext('Level 1', font, mainwindow, 150, 100)
pygame.display.update()
time.sleep(1)

displaytext('Press any key to begin...', font, mainwindow, 22, 200)
pygame.display.update()
waitforplayer()

while True:
    number = 1
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == ord('a') or event.key == K_LEFT:
                moveleft = True
                moveright = False
            if event.key == ord('d') or event.key == K_RIGHT:
                moveleft = False
                moveright = True
            if event.key == ord('g'):
                bmoveup = True
                if number == 1:
                    bmoveleft = True
                else:
                    bmoveright = True
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == ord('a') or event.key == K_LEFT:
                moveleft = False
            if event.key == ord('d') or event.key == K_RIGHT:
                moveright = False

    if moveleft and paddlerect.left > 0:
        paddlerect.left -= SPEED
    if moveright and paddlerect.right < WINDOWWIDTH:
        paddlerect.right += SPEED

    if bmovedown and ballrect.bottom < WINDOWHEIGHT:
        ballrect.top += BALLSPEED
    if bmoveup and ballrect.top > 0:
        ballrect.top -= BALLSPEED
    if bmoveleft and ballrect.left > 0:
        ballrect.left -= BALLSPEED
    if bmoveright and ballrect.right < WINDOWWIDTH:
        ballrect.right += BALLSPEED

    if ballrect.top <= 0:
        bmovedown = not bmovedown
        bmoveup = not bmoveup
    if ballrect.left <= 0:
        bmoveleft = not bmoveleft
        bmoveright = not bmoveright
    if ballrect.right >= WINDOWWIDTH:
        bmoveleft = not bmoveleft
        bmoveright = not bmoveright
    if ballrect.bottom >= WINDOWHEIGHT:
        bmovedown = not bmovedown
        bmoveup = not bmoveup

    mainwindow.fill(WHITE)
    mainwindow.blit(paddle, paddlerect)
    mainwindow.blit(ball, ballrect)


    for b in range(len(level1blocks)):
        mainwindow.blit(level1blocks[b], level1rects[b])

    for i in level1rects[:]:
        if ballrect.colliderect(i):
            level1blocks.remove(i)
            level1rects.remove(i)
            bmovedown = not bmovedown
            bmoveup = not bmoveup
            bmoveleft = not bmoveleft
            bmoveright = not bmoveright


    if ballrect.colliderect(paddlerect):
        bmovedown = not bmovedown
        bmoveup = not bmoveup
        bmoveleft = not bmoveleft
        bmoveright = not bmoveright




    pygame.display.update()
    fpsclock.tick(35)
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python32/brick breaker", line 140, in <module>
    if ballrect.colliderect(i):
TypeError: Argument must be rect style object
```

I have no clue how to solve this error, please help.

Comment: [learning to debug](https://plone.org/documentation/kb/using-pdb) is always worthwhile

Comment: `(this is random text that is necessary so I can post all this code)` what a clever solution to the problem. I assume thinking about the error message and improving the question would've taken too much effort?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that pygame expects everything in the array `level1rects` to be a rectange, and in this case, you must have something in that array that isn't.

Comment: OP's removing elements from the original list while iterating over a copy of it. It's not a good idea to iterate over a list and remove elements from it at the same time.

Comment: Ah, woops, I didn't notice he was removing items from the list, never mind then.

Comment: @Blender What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: @user1952081 If you look at the history of the answer, I told you that you didn't need to make a copy of the array to iterate over it. Blender pointed out I was wrong, so I deleted that part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `level1rects` is currently a list of tuples, not rects because of:

```
rbrect = rb.get_rect().topleft = (0, 0)
rb1rect = rb1.get_rect().topleft = (40, 0)
rb2rect = rb2.get_rect().topleft = (80, 0)
level1rects = [rbrect, rb1rect, rb2rect]
```